# MySQL JOIN for Cohort Analysis

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables to work with, USERS, METRICS_DAILY

mysql> describe USERS;

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
    | Field                     | Type                | Null | Key | Default                                  | Extra          |
    +---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
    | USER_ID                   | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                                     | auto_increment |
    | CREATED                   | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

mysql> describe METRICS_DAILY;

```
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| USER_ID | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| EVENT   | tinyint(3) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DATE    | date                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| COUNT   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to select count distinct USER_ID where where DATE=DATE(NOW())  and EVENT in (x,y,z) and USERS.CREATED is month1, month2, month3, ... monthCURRENT.

I could almost do it entirely in the METRICS_DAILY table because I have the DATE correspodinging to USERS.CREATED, just indirectly.

Created is a full timestamp.  I need to break it down to cohorts by monthly CREATED.

Heres a start:

SELECT count(distinct METRICS_DAILY.USER_ID),CREATED,MONTH(CREATED),DATE FROM METRICS_DAILY LEFT JOIN USERS ON (METRICS_DAILY.USER_ID = USERS.USER_ID) where EVENT > 10 and DATE=DATE(NOW()) group by MONTH(CREATED);

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| count(distinct METRICS_DAILY.USER_ID) | CREATED             | MONTH(CREATED) | DATE       |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
|                                     3 | 2013-01-14 09:35:16 |              1 | 2013-01-18 |
|                                    16 | 2012-12-15 07:07:49 |             12 | 2013-01-18 |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: So, this kind of seems like it might be two questions, which should really be asked separately. The first is how to do the JOIN (which isn't really clear) and the other is how to change CREATED from a full timestamp into bins of month. Am I getting what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(u.CREATED), YEAR(u.CREATED), COUNT(*) AS UserCount
FROM METRICS_DAILY md
JOIN USERS u
ON u.USER_ID = md.USER_ID
WHERE md.DATE = NOW() AND md.EVENT in (x,y,z)
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(u.CREATED), YEAR(u.CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(`METRICS_DAILY`.`DATE`) AS `Day of DATE`, `METRICS_DAILY`.`EVENT` AS `EVENT`, COUNT(DISTINCT `METRICS_DAILY`.`USER_ID`) AS `Number of unique User Id`
  FROM METRICS_DAILY
  JOIN USERS ON `METRICS_DAILY`.`USER_ID` = `USERS`.`USER_ID`
  WHERE (`METRICS_DAILY`.`EVENT` >= "31") AND (`METRICS_DAILY`.`DATE` BETWEEN "2012-12-01" AND "2012-12-31") AND (`USERS`.`CREATED` BETWEEN CAST("2012-12-01" AS DATETIME) AND CAST(CONCAT("2012-12-31", " 23:59:59") AS DATETIME))
  GROUP BY DATE(`METRICS_DAILY`.`DATE`), `METRICS_DAILY`.`EVENT`
  ORDER BY `Day of DATE` ASC, `EVENT` ASC;
```